# In Node.js, why isn't my PNG file read correctly?

Tags: node.js, png

I'm trying to use the following package:

https://github.com/photopea/UPNG.js/

with the following image:

[image]

My code is as follows:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const png = require("upng-js");

async function run() {
    try {
        const data = png.decode(await fs.readFile("./qr.png"));
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
}

run();
```

This gives me the following error message:

```
The input is not a PNG file!
```

Why is my PNG file not being properly read?

Comment: `fs.readFile` doesn't return a promise. So awaiting it has no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use readFileSync instead of readFile or promisify the readFile method

```
const fs = require("fs");
const png = require("upng-js");
const Promise = require('bluebird');

async function run() {
    try {
        const data = png.decode(await Promise.promisify(fs.readFile)("./qr.png"));
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
}

run();
```

Answer (score 0):

Wait for the file using callback

```
const fs = require("fs");
const png = require("upng-js");

async function run() {
    try {
        fs.readFile("./qr.png", function(err,content){
            if(!err) {
                const data = png.decode(content);
            }
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
}

run();
```